# How to create custom MessageBox in Android application?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am new to Android application, i want to show confirm MessageBox in my Android application and want to get result (which button clicked, as in .Net Windows Application).

Answer (score 0):

To get the result of the AlertDialog Please try as below,

```
String Result="";

public void Alert(String text, String title)
    { 
        AlertDialog dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(text);
        if(!title.equals("") && !text.equals(""))
        {
            dialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            Result="OK";
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setButton2("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            Result="Cancel";
                        }
                    });
        }

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Thank you.