# Show Notification in try-catch block

Tags: android, notifications

I want to use `Notification` inside the try-catch block, located inside a click listener of a button.

But when I place the notification in catch block it show following error:

> "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"

Comment: did you forget to include your code?

Comment: Check this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859167/how-to-create-custom-messagebox-in-android-application/10344670#10344670

Comment: @ Waqas
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   
   public void onClick(View v) {
                         Code Goes here 
try{}
catch(Exception e){
notification goes here}
this is dummy View of Code 
}});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not give any code (why not? I mean, come on :)  ), but you are probably doing a call inside the listener with `this`.

You are expecting the `this` to be your `Activity`, but instead it is the `OnClickListener` you are in. Hence the errror: there is no constructor that takes an `OnClickListener` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

the builder constructor requires context, you must do something like

```
AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Builder constructor requires a `context`.
I presume (because you havnt pasted any code, you should !) you want to show the dialog inside the OnClickListener method using an anonymous type.
When you are inside you anonymous listener, `this` will refer to the OnClickListener object which is not a context.
So either :
1) Dont use an anonymous OnClickListener but let your class implement OnClickListener
2) Use `NameOfYourClass.this` instead of `this` to say that you want this to be considered as a your Class and not as the OnClickListener
3) use the view as context

Please, next time, paste your code !